# SQL Developer "Comparing with" menu is missing

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm triying to compare two packages on the same schema.
To do that it supossed to show this menu:

[image]

but in my case that menu appears empty...

[image]

any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

best regards

Comment: Which SQL Developer **versions** are we talking about? Above is ..., and bottom is ...?

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot above is just an image that i found out at google search on this result:

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/10/how-to-compare-plsql-and-sql-in-oracle-sql-developer/

and bottom is the version installed at my computer which is :  Versión 19.4.0.354

Comment: I see. It is kind of strange that there's nothing in the "Comparar" menu, although there's the "arrow" icon which suggests that there *should be* something there. I don't have 19.4 so I can't try it myself, but - I just tried it on 21.4, it works just fine. As SQL Developer is free to download and use, perhaps you could / should upgrade?

Comment: also is working as expected for me on 21.4.3...maybe try restarting/reconnecting if you can't upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

i use sql developer Version 22.2.1.234 on early installation compare with show sub menu, but after few month it gone. but i can access it via :

File > Compare with > ...